# storing a value in a memory address from sting or int

Tags: c, linux, kernel

1. i need to change the value in a memory location to an int value.
   The problem is that i am working in kernel using c and i only recieve this address as a string from user space like so "0xbfac6d78" i have managed to convert this hex value to a long int value which gives me -1079218824. The question is how can i use what i have to change what is stored in this address to some int value?
2. i have tried this but i get segfault:

   ```
   *(long int*)value = 3;
   //where value is a long int variable with the value -1079218824 stored in it
   *(int*)buff = 3;
   //where buff is just a string with 0xbfac6d78 stored in it
   ```

And yes this address has already been mallocd;

Comment: You have to use an unsigned int:  `uint64_t` your value should be 3215748472

Comment: You can't directly dereference a user pointer from the kernel. Need to use one of the copy_to macros.  Namely copy_to_user.

Comment: @Ôrel: Why do you assume `uint64_t` rather than `uint32_t`?

Comment: Is this string `"0xbfac6d78"` supposed to represent a user space address? Why is it being passed as a string rather than as a pointer?